# Como Sugerir nome ao salvar relatório Crystal Report

Tags: .net, relatório, crystal-reports

Alguém sabe como sugerir nome ao salvar relatório Crystal Report C#, na caixa de dialogo, windows form?
O formato já consegui restringir...assim:

```
crystalRVEditoraNomeComeca.AllowedExportFormats = (int)(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ViewerExportFormats.ExcelRecordFormat);
```

Abaixo imagem para ajudar na compreensão:
[image: Sugerir Nome]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funcionou assim :

```
ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
rd.SummaryInfo.ReportTitle = "Nome Desejado";
```

Answer (score 2):

Veja se isso resolve, nessa exportação, é utilizada uma classe de opções para a exportação. Nela a propriedade **DiskFileName** é o nome do arquivo.

```
ExportOptions CrExportOptions ;
                DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
                PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
                CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = "c:\\csharp.net-informations.pdf";
                CrExportOptions = cryRpt.ExportOptions;
                {
                    CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                    CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                    CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
                    CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
                }
                cryRpt.Export();
```

Comment: Não funcionou...somente salvou no endereço DiskFileName...